# Python logging import inconsistent to print

Tags: python, logging, formatting

When using logger this

```
Import logging
logging.info(
    f"This is a  \nid: {id}", \
    f"\nclaim number: {claim_number}")
```

causes the error `TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting`
whereas

```
print(
    f"This is a  \nid: {id}", \
    f"\nclaim number: {claim_number}")
```

works fine

I am wondering what the neatest way to do this with the logger is, there are multiple lines so i want to split them by line per item

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I may have misinterpreted what you meant, but I guess just using normal **f-strings** would do the trick instead of using **"\"** for splitting the log record.

Try this instead:

```py
logging.info(f"This is a\nid: {id}\nclaim number: {claim_number}")
```

And in case you just want to span your log record over multiple lines, just try writing your code something like this:

```py
logging.info(f"This is a\nid: {id}"
             f"\nclaim number: {claim_number}"
             f"\nSome other stuff: {some_other_stuff}"
             f"\nThis method can be used even if there "
             f"is nothing to format.")
```